# Extend Image Watch With COLUMN-major matrix type

Tags: visual-studio, opencv, image-processing, natvis

I want to extend [Image Watch](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=WolfKienzle.ImageWatch) with a *.natvis description for my own matrix class. The data in this matrix class is stored in column major format, in contrast to the row major order of OpenCV.

I were able to display my matrices *like transposed* with the following code:

```
<Item Name="[width]">m_Rows</Item>
<Item Name="[height]">m_Cols</Item>
<Item Name="[data]">m_pData</Item>
<Item Name="[stride]">m_Rows*sizeof($T1)</Item>
```

Is their a way to display column major matrices correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing the stride to simply

`<Item Name="[stride]">sizeof($T1)</Item>`

?